# How to remove Powershell from Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell

I want to remove Powershell from Windows Server 2012. I have removed it in Windows XP by removing its updates. Also, when I removed Powershell from "Remove Role and Feature" I lost my GUI!  Would you tell me what's the solution?

Comment: You really don't want to remove PowerShell. How can you manage the server without it?

Comment: I want to ban other users to access it

Comment: That's a completely different question.

Comment: Powershell is part of the 'Core' of that OS and as such cannot be removed. Do you try and remove cmd.exe as well?

Comment: As I commented already in the answer, removing powershell, or even locking up powershell is most certainly the wrong approach.

Answer (score 8):

Powershell is a essential component of Windows Server 2012. You can't just remove it. It's nearly like you want to remove the bash shell from an debian / ubuntu / etc. server. If you want to make the Powershell inaccessible from other users you have to check the user rights and may also disable Powershell remoting.

Also with non-administrative rights you can't do very critical things on an server. Even not with powershell. If you give other user critical rights, they could damage you system even if your system would't have the powershell...

Comment: I agree. Windows is designed in a way that makes it very difficult, even for professional users, to damage a system with a default user account and default user permissions. And if there is a way to damage a system with user rights, there is also a way to do it without powershell.